# Java concurrency in practice Listing10.6 synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Listing from jcip 10.6

```
 @ThreadSafe 
 class Taxi { 
 @GuardedBy("this") private Point location, destination; 
 private final Dispatcher dispatcher; 
 ... 
 public synchronized Point getLocation() { 
 return location; 
 }      
 public synchronized void setLocation(Point location) { 
 boolean reachedDestination; 
 synchronized (this) { 
 this.location = location; 
 reachedDestination = location.equals(destination); 
 } 
 if (reachedDestination) 
 dispatcher.notifyAvailable(this); 
 } 
} 

@ThreadSafe 
class Dispatcher { 
 @GuardedBy("this") private final Set<Taxi> taxis; 
 @GuardedBy("this") private final Set<Taxi> availableTaxis; 
 ... 
 public synchronized void notifyAvailable(Taxi taxi) { 
 availableTaxis.add(taxi); 
 } 

 public Image getImage() { 
 Set<Taxi> copy; 
 synchronized (this) { 
 copy = new HashSet<Taxi>(taxis); 
 } 
 Image image = new Image(); 
 for (Taxi t : copy) 
 image.drawMarker(t.getLocation()); 
 return image; 
 } 
}
```

My question is:
Class Taxi, method setLocation used synchronized by "this" twice: first in method call, and second inside method. 
Is first synchronized redundant?

Method getLocation is synchronized also.
For what purpose is it synchronized?
Since set reference is atomic in java i think there is impossible to return corrupt location value. So i think synchronized on getLoction is also redundant.

One more question:
If I make location valotile, is it acceptible to get rid of synchronized in getLocation?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This must have been a mistake in previous prints, my version of JCIP 10.6 has this `setLocation()` method :

```
public void setLocation(Point location) {
    boolean reachedDestination;
    synchronized (this) {
        this.location = location;
        reachedDestination = location.equals(destination);
    }
    if (reachedDestination)
        dispatcher.notifyAvailable(this);
}
```

without method level `synchronized`.

Synchronization on the getter is needed to ensure it does not return a stale value.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately different prints has different versions. Mine paper print has this method without `synchronized` too, although PDF version - with one.

Comment: The version on the website still has the extraneous `synchronized`. :-(

Answer (score 4):

See http://jcip.net.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/errata.html

> p.214: In Listing 10.6, Taxi.setLocation should not be a synchronized method. (The synchronized block in its body is correct, however.)

Answer (score 1):

If `setLocation` has a method lock, I do think the inner lock is redundant. Probably, the method lock should not be there.

However, `getLocation` does need a lock, for memory visibility purposes. In particular, if `getLocation` were not `synchronized`, then updates done to `location` by `setLocation` may not be visible to a different thread, and `getLocation` could return a previous value for `location`.

Comment: Agreed, one more question:
If I make location valotile, is it acceptible to get rid of synchronized in getLocation?